# When I finished University or When I finish University or When I have finished University

Tags: grammar, meaning, tense

I want to write about a future situation when I graduate my university.
I'm currently going to university.
What is best sentence and what is difference between the three?

> - When I **finished** University
> - When I **finish** University
> - When I **have finished** University

Comment: *When I finished university* is not for a future situation. You need verbs to tell that - *When I will have finished...*, for example.

Comment: I do not think the statement *”When I will have”* is grammatical.    Proceed with caution!   The question “When **will I have** done x?” is correct, and the statement “In two years, **I will have**” is correct.  But “*When I will have done x*” is not correct, or at least sounds very awkward. It would almost always be better said, “When I **have**”.

Answer (score 1):

> When I finished University

This is used to talk about the past, since you're using the past tense: "finish**ed**"

> When I finish University

This can be used to talk about a planned future.

Example: "When I finish University, I'll move out."

This means *I* will move out when (usually the moment) *I* finish University.

> When I have finished university

This is *present perfect* tense. This would be the *best* option for your situation.

Example: "I'll get a job *when I've finished University*."

This means *I* plan to get a job *some time* after having finished University.

While the second case (*finish*) tends to point to a short time (often a moment) right after the *action* (finish University), the third case tends to point to *any* time after the *action*, which means it can be 2 years after finishing University.

Comment: I think** when I have finished my university ** is present perfect referring to future time.

Comment: You're right. My mistake.